# How to use WaitForActivity in Visual Studio workflow for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am creating Visual Studio Workflow for SharePoint and want to use activity 'WaitForActivity' in my code, that will check one property of workflow item if its not set then it will pause the execution and as soon as this property set, continue the execution of workflow.

If I use 'WhileActivity' for same then only one item shows WF status "in progress" and other items is in "Starting" state.

So how do I add 'WaitForActivity' in my workflow as there is no such activity in visual studio 2013 toolbox.

What I want to do in 'WaitForActivity' code is as below

```
private void CheckForField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
SPListItem item = workflowProperties.List.GetItemById(workflowProperties.ItemId);
            if (item[FieldName] != null)
            {
                isPropTrue = (bool)item[FieldName];
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using any of the out of the box workflow tools and you're just writing your own code, I think you'll have to either put in a delayActivity that sleeps for x amount of time, checks the item and then either goes back to sleep, acts or ends the workflow based on whatever criteria.